# Does anyone know how I dynamically change this variable?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, api, fetch-api

I would like to be able to change which data gets targetted in "immutable_data" depending on what arg I put with the "renderTags" function, what would be the best way to do this? I've tried lots of different things but it's not getting the right object, thanks

```
async function renderTags(args) {
    let atts = await fetchAtt();
    var flags = [], output = [], l = atts.data.length, i;
        for( i=0; i<l; i++) {
    if( flags[atts.data[i].immutable_data.ARGS]) continue;
    flags[atts.data[i].immutable_data.ARGS] = true;
    output.push(atts.data[i].immutable_data.ARGS); 
}console.log(output);

}

renderTags(variant);
```

I am fetching an API, loop all the "atts.data" and uniquely storing my chosen bit of data from inside the data's immutable.data. For example my

```
renderTags(variant)
```

will look for

```
atts.data[i].immutable_data.variant
```

and

```
renderTags(name);
```

should look like

```
atts.data[i].immutable_data.name
```

,etc.

Comment: https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: updated the open post

Comment: Instead of `.ARGS`, use dynamic property access (much like you already do with `i`): `[args]`.